# Poisson Distribution - dealing with big numbers

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

*The mean number of defective products produced in a factory in one day is **21**. 
What is the probability that in a given day there are exactly **12** defective products?*

I get some big numbers when I try to answer this question and they don't make sense !

I used a Poisson Distribution calculator to get the answer
**0.0116**

But when I use my calculator  to figure it out I get 
 **1.0917004899798243054141947918587e-13**

Where am I going wrong?

I use the basic formula for Poisson Distribution

[image]

The mean is **21**

and **X** is **12**

Comment: Hey. Can you perhaps edit your post to include the following? What Poisson parameter do you use, where did you get the "Poisson Distribution calculator" from, and what did you type in to your calculator?

Comment: I would say $P(N=12)=\frac{(21)^{12} e^{-21}}{12!}\doteq 0.0116$

Comment: dang it ! after reading your post I realized where I went wrong ! I used the mean for x ! and divided into that !  I only  started reading about Poisson Distribution yesterday , so thats my excuse!

Answer (score 0):

Poisson is used when n tends to infinite and the probability tends to zero. In my opinion you should try using Binomial Distribution.

Comment: No. To compute the probability that a Poisson random variable with a given parameter is equal to some given value, one should definitely use the exact Poisson distribution.